# Appending a data frame with list as row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am calculating the Levenshtein distance between the input text and a list. I want to store this information in a data frame for further analysis later.

I am having issues assigning this list produced by my function to the created dataframe.

```
col_list = data_df.clean_text_items.unique()
levenshtein_ratio_matrix_df = pd.DataFrame(columns= col_list)

def levenshtein_compare_to_list(row):
    row_levenshtein_ratio = []

    for i in collist:
        row_levenshtein_ratio.append(levenshtein (row['clean_text_source_item'], i))

    levenshtein_ratio_matrix_df.append(row_levenshtein_ratio)

for index, row in data_df.iterrows():
    levenshtein_compare_to_list(row)
```

The following runs, and if I print out row_levensthein_ratio per loop it shows the correct values, but it doesn't actually append the data frame.  (levenshtein_ratio_matrix_df is left blank)

Comment: can you provide some sample data by any chance? Also, there is a typo in the line **for i in collist:** collist should be col_list.

Comment: col_list = ndarray of text of strings, matching the n elements in the list below.
row_levenstein_ratio = List,  [0.0, 8.0, 11.0, 28.0]

Comment: I think the issue lies in this statement FWIW.

 levenshtein_ratio_matrix_df.append(row_levenshtein_ratio)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
  df_length = len(levenshtein_ratio_matrix_df)
  levenshtein_ratio_matrix_df.loc[df_length] = row_levenshtein_ratio
```

Instead of

```
 levenshtein_ratio_matrix_df.append(row_levenshtein_ratio)
```